# Use SoundTouch framework in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, soundtouch

Can you please tell me how to use the [SoundTouch framework](https://github.com/fivebats/FBAudio/tree/master/FBAudioLib/SoundTouch.framework) in a Swift iOS project to detect BPM? I tried all things with Bridging Headers & whatever but I cant get it work... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you still need it to use SoundTouch in your iOS project, I have shared a GitHub repository with that libraries compiled for `armv7`, `armv7s`, `arm64`, `i386` and `x86_64`

https://github.com/enrimr/soundtouch-ios-library

To implement that compiled library in your project, you have to add SoundTouch directory (which includes libSoundTouch.a and the directory with headers) in your Xcode project.

In SWIFT you can't import a .h so you will need to create a .h file named `<Your-Project-Name>-Bridging-Header-File.h`
Then reference it in your projects build settings (under "Swift Compiler" look for "Objective C Bridging Header") with:

```
$(SRCROOT)/<Your-Project-Name>-Bridging-Header.h
```

And now you must be able to use SoundTouch class.

Comment: I've did exactly that and I'm getting `Unknown type name 'namespace'`.

Comment: same problem, " Unknown type name 'namespace' "

Comment: Yes, not able to compile with swift

Answer (score 1):

**The soundtouch library is originally written in C++ which Swift won't compile.**

Even with an updated soundtouch library, the lib won't compile in a Swift project without Objective-C wrappers to allow Swift to access the methodology.

*Using a bridging header will indeed include the soundtouch library, but the project just won't compile there after.*

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Swift in your project, so I can suggest to use this lib:

https://github.com/Luccifer/BPM-Analyser

```
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TestMusic", ofType: "m4a"),
let url = URL(string: filePath) else {return "error occured, check fileURL"}
BPMAnalyzer.core.getBpmFrom(url, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No disclaimer and subject to Superpowered license.